# How to query local system time and time from network server using NodaTime

Tags: c#, ntp, nodatime

apologized for asking a bit different question regarding NodaTime because my hands are not well familiar with this library NodaTime. so looking for advise and suggestion to achieve my goal.

i want to use Nodatime library to get date and time from local pc. this is nodatime library repository https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime

and i found another nodatime repository for NTP date and time. here is the repository url https://github.com/mj1856/NodaTime.NetworkClock

now i have confusion which one i should use as a result which help me to get local time and network time using single library.

if i add the dll from both repository then any problem would occur....like to know in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NodaTime` is a *dependency* of `NodaTime.NetworkClock`.  You need them both if you want the network clock feature.

This is a very common practice when one library provides the core features and another library extends it with additional functionality.

Install from Nuget:

```powershell
Install-Package NodaTime.NetworkClock
```

And you will also get the `NodaTime` package automatically installed as well.

Then use them simply like this:

```
Instant currentSystemTime = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
Instant currentNetworkTime = NetworkClock.Instance.Now;
```

Comment: thanks for answer. so you mean just using extended one would suffice to get local and network time? why did u say `u need both` does it mean that i need to add two dll files for one for core nodatime and one extended nodatime for network clock.

Comment: i guess this syntax `SystemClock.Instance.Now;` automatically return datetime based on current pc timezone wise ? i have seen people always mention time zone info when they work with NodaTime. thanks

Comment: Both clocks return an `Instant` - which is UTC based.  Read more on the [Noda Time web site](http://nodatime.org/) and in the [NetworkClock readme](https://github.com/mj1856/NodaTime.NetworkClock/blob/master/README.md) for how to adjust that instant to to a specific time zone.

Comment: Yes, you will end up with two dlls added to your project.  `NodaTime.dll` will provide the core Noda Time features, and `NodaTime.NetworkClock.dll` will provide the network clock functions.